# Do you know why it appears "BadMethodCallException Method [validateEquired] does not exist"?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the method store() to create a new registration type for  the conference. But it appears an error "BadMethodCallException
Method [validateEquired] does not exist."  in the file "Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php".

Do you know why?

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $rules = [
        'registration_type_name' => 'required',
        'registration_type_capacity' => 'required|integer|min:0',
        'registration_type_price' => 'required|integer|min:0',
        'registration_type_minimum' => 'equired|integer|min:1',
        'registration_type_maximum' => 'rgt:registration_type_minimum|required|integer|min:1',
    ];

    $customMessages = [
        'registration_type_name.required' => 'The field name is rqeuired.',
        'registration_type_capacity.integer' => 'The field capacity needs to be a positive integer.',
        ....
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
    $conference = Conference::find($id);


    RegistrationType::create([
        'name' => $request->registration_type_name,
        'description' => $request->registration_type_description,
        'capacity' => $request->registration_type_capacity,
        'price' => $request->registration_type_price,
        'min_participants' => $request->registration_type_minimum,
        'max_participants' => $request->registration_type_maximum,
        'conference_id' => $conference->id
    ]);

    Session::flash('success', 'Registration type created.');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an `r` here:

```
'registration_type_minimum' => 'equired|integer|min:1',
                                ^
```